# When i connect to wifi with my PC , other devices can't connect

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, android, lan, wifi-configuration

I have a strange problem here

when my pc is off , phones(android) in the house can connect to wifi normally the time when i connect to the wifi , they can't connect anymore (connected but without access to internet)

I have another PC so i turned off my pc and open this one , connecting to net and they can connect also , so I understand that the problem is about my pc ..

I'll search , i had tried many things but the problem can't be passed Router is configured perfectly (WIFI config )

I don't remember that i configure the network so when i connect no one connect .

aah another thing (very wrd) : my own phone (especially my phone) can connect when i'm connecting with my pc !!

so , any suggestion , help ..

Comment: Perhaps at some time you cloned the PC's MAC address to your router or modem.

Comment: can you explain more

Answer (score 1):

Check if you PC isn't using the very address of the router and creating a conflict. Some devices such as your phone may have cached the IP-to-MAC correspondence and therefore are still able to talk to the router.

1) if you have an `arp` command on your 2nd PC, use the command (`arp -n`) with your first PC disconnected, and then with your PC connected, and check if they are different, and post here.

2) Due to ARP caching, devices (PCs or phones) that are connected to the LAN before your PC connects to it will have a valid IP<->MAC table. Those that boot (or disconnect/reconnect) will have an ARP table built with your PC in it. So if it's an ARP problem, after disconnecting the phone, connecting the bad PC, and reconnecting the phone, the phone should not be able to use Internet.

Comment: my PC has a static @ : 192.168.1.23 , 
can you tell me what can the problem can be if you understand the pb ? 
if i format the pc (and i dont want) it will works ?

Comment: Disconnect you PC, and see if other machines on the network can still ping 192.168.1.23. If yes, then you have an address conflict. You shouldn't use static addresses, normally you get an address assigned by the DHCP server in the router. If it does its job correctly and unless you have dozens of devices you will still get the same address each time.

Comment: we have about 6 devices at home so the dhcp server doesnt depasse 192.168.1.10 in worth cases , for that i attach this ip to my pc cuz it shold be static for the server ..
+ i tried to ping .23 but : inaccessible 
@xenoid

Comment: in your first reply , you say " cached the IP-to-MAC correspondence"
can you explain it more ?

Comment: He's saying you may need to wait five minutes or so between disconnecting the PC and pinging.

Comment: i dont understand why if i disconnect they can connect 
the time i connect they can not connect anymore 
i test this about 10 times ,
i connect after 1s they cant connect
i disconnect after 1s they can connect 
logically , i can't find a reason

Comment: I don't understand what you're saying. Can you disconnect the problem PC from the network, wait five minutes, and then try to ping `192.168.1.23` (from another device still connected to the network) and tell us what happens?

Comment: Edited my answer. Also, try with your PC on a DHCP address.